# UDP (сокет) соединение без открытия портов на Minecraft сервере

Tags: minecraft, bukkit-api

Вопрос в заголовке. Как соеденить сайт/приложение с сервером маинкрафт без открытия портов (т.к. хостинг не позволяет). Хостинг для каждого клиента выделяет не поддомен а порт.

1. Нужно через сокет соединить Java плагин с сайтом(ReactJS)
2. На сервере установлен плагин, который является UDP сервером и слушает порт 60606. Но это не возможно, т.к. этот порт закрыт или занят

Comment: Можно использовать всякие ухищрения типа OpenVPN через TOR, Tox, Telegram, но это будет **не быстро**

Comment: закрыт или занят?

Comment: сайт или приложение? хостинг с сайтом или с майнкрафтом?

Answer (score 2):

Такие соединения решаются посредством STUN. Этот фокус позволяет открыть UDP порт на некоторое время, а потом уже самим приложением поддерживать открытое соединение.

Comment: У сервера есть только 1 порт, для подключения игрока к серверу и обмена данными. И как сделать то что вы написали в Bukkit Java плагине

Comment: и? количество портов не важно. напишите больше подробностей что за сайт и приложение. где размещён сервер, а где сайт. какие настройки сети на обоих хостах.

Comment: Сайт на React JS. Хостинг: Falixnodes. Хочу их соеденить сокетами. И ещё стоит плагин который открывет UDP соединение с клиентом на порту 60606 (естественно он закрыт). Последнее не обязательно, но буду рад если это тоже можно решить

Comment: в вопросе опишите с примерами и с настройкой сети

Comment: что подразумевается под настройкой сети?

Comment: когда ответ ждать?

Comment: после того как обновите вопрос где какая программа и настройки сети

Comment: Я обновил вопрос